# How to pass in an object to component then to src for Image?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to make passing in an object as a property but I run into this error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error: Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to > the `next/image` component. Received: {}

I've tried using the ...props but the same error persists.

I'm using Next JS with Material UI.  Here's a slimmed down version of what I'm working on with only the relevant parts.

See that `myIcon` is being passed down.

#### index.js

```
import myIcon from '../public/icon.png' 
import TripleCard from './tripleCard'

<TripleCard cardData={{ icon: {myIcon}, size: "100px" }}></TripleCard>
```

#### tripleCard.js

```
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function TripleCard({ cardData }) {
    return(
        <Image src={cardData.icon} height={cardData.size}/>
    )
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `icon: {myIcon}` with `icon: myIcon` when passing the `cardData` prop.

Comment: Now I get this 
> ./components/singleCard.js:16:17
> Syntax error: JSX value should be either an expression > or a 
> quoted JSX text

Comment: What part of the code is that error referring to? Can you please add that to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the objects in the console and realized that the image object was nested inside the `Icon` object.

What I thought:

```
cardData
|_ icon
```

Reality:

```
props
|_ cardData 
|__ icon 
|___ myIcon
```

so `tripleCard.js` should look like this:

```
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function TripleCard({ props }) {
    return(
        <Image src={props.cardData.icon.myIcon} height={props.cardData.size}/>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check you directory for myIcon.

Comment: I can confirm this is  not the issue since I used the Image object in both files and it worked fine.